# Not able to locate element in selenium 3.0

Tags: java, selenium

I am writing a script to locate "login" and click on it for an web based application but I am getting exception:

> no such element: Unable to locate element

My code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\Selenium\\drivers\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://www.wayn.com"); //to find login
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='TopMenu']/div[1]/div/div[2]/login-buttons/div/div[1]/div[1]"))
                  .sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask]. Please provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way.

```
driver.get("http://www2.wayn.com");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='button big left red ng-isolate-scope'][@wayn-log-click='loginButtonsLogClick']")).click();
```

**Explanation of xpath:** Use `class` and `wayn-log-click` attribute along with `<div>` tag.

**Suggestion :-** Instead of using `absolute xpath`, use `relative xpath`.

Comment: Please Mark this answer as `Accepted` if it's resolved your issue. 
For more details on how to accept an answer, refer this post: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

try waiting a little for element to be visible:

```
WebDriverWait wait =new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("username")));

driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("username");
driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("password");
```